# I want to use out parameter ,but I am not getting the proper syntax of doing so,:ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: plsql

Problem definition: Create a procedure which will display the employees in descending order of employee name of
computer department.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_disp (name     OUT VARCHAR2,
                                     age      OUT NUMBER,
                                     dep      OUT VARCHAR,
                                     salary   OUT NUMBER)
AS
    CURSOR c
    IS
          SELECT name,
                 age,
                 department,
                 salary
            FROM enployee2
           WHERE department = 'Computer'
        ORDER BY name DESC;

    this_name   enployee2.name%TYPE;
    this_age    enployee2.age%TYPE;
    this_dep    enployee2.department%TYPE;
    this_sal    enployee2.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;

    LOOP
        FETCH c1
            INTO this_name,
                 this_age,
                 this_dep,
                 this_sal;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            this_name || ' ' || this_age || ' ' || this_dep || ' 
'             || this_sal);
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

Maybe there is a problem in my execution part...

execution part:

```
variable nm varchar2(50);
variable age number
variable dep varchar2(50);
variable sal number;
execute  pr_disp(nm,age,dep,sal);
```

.The error comes when I execute the code is :ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: What is the error which you get? Post that with your question as well

Comment: I have edited the question...Please help sir to solve  this error

Comment: Confusion... if you need to display on console using dbms_output then why you are passing the OUT parameters to procedure. If you are just capturing the names without passing filter criteria then why not use the query itself rather than using procedure. Also two big logical issuesi see are...first you are capturing the values in local variables but are not assigning them to out params. Second, in case of multiple records you will need a table of type records to respond back otherwise in return you will always get data for single employee not all. A little more description will help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several errors. Please see below to find out what and where:

Table Creation:

```
create   table enployee2(  name  VARCHAR2(100),
                                    age NUMBER,
                                    department  VARCHAR2(100),
                                    salary NUMBER
                                    );

INSERT INTO enployee2 VALUES ('AAA',32,'Computer',2344);
INSERT INTO enployee2 VALUES ('BBB',42,'Computer',4400);
insert into enployee2 values ('CCC',21,'Computer',2454);
```

Procedure:

```
Create OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_disp(
                                    name OUT VARCHAR2,
                                    age OUT NUMBER,
                                    dep OUT VARCHAR,
                                    salary OUT NUMBER)
AS
  CURSOR c --<-- Your cursor name is `C` but you used it as `C1` below while opening and closing
  IS
    SELECT name,
      age,
      department,
      salary
    FROM enployee2
    WHERE department ='Computer'
    ORDER BY name DESC;

  this_name enployee2.name%type;
  this_age enployee2.age%type;
  this_dep enployee2.department%type;
  this_sal enployee2.salary%TYPE;

BEGIN
  OPEN c; --<--Opening `C1` while your cursor name is `C`
  LOOP
    FETCH c INTO this_name,this_age,this_dep,this_sal;
    dbms_output.put_line(this_name||' '||this_age||' '||this_dep||' '||this_sal);
    EXIT   WHEN c%NOTFOUND; --<--Exiting `C1` while your cursor name is `C`
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c; --<--Closing `C1` while your cursor name is `C`
END;
/
```

Execution:

```
DECLARE
  nm  VARCHAR2(50);
  age NUMBER;
  dep VARCHAR2(50);
  sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
  pr_disp(nm,age,dep,sal);
END;
```

Comment: thnx a lot xing

Comment: This helped me a lot sir !!Thnx for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a PL/SQL-Block like this:

```
DECLARE
    nm    VARCHAR2 (50);
    age   NUMBER; -- here you were missing a semi-colon
    dep   VARCHAR2 (50);
    sal   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    pr_disp (nm,
             age,
             dep,
             sal);
END;
```

Comment: thnx a lot sir!!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your stored procedure is invalid because of compilation errors. Try compiling again and check the messages.

You can also check the status with:

```
select status from user_objects where object_name='PR_DISP';
```

If it's INVALID you should be able to obtain error messages also via:

```
select * from user_errors where name = 'PR_DISP';
```

Maybe your table is named employee2 (not enployee2)?

Btw: What are the out parameters for? You never use them.